# Object showing class variables with ToString methos

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, object, tostring

From what I gathered I need a constructor but where on Earth do I specify this variables data? and how this ToStringmethod suppose to work? moreover, I am using Visual studio and when I try to debug this code to see if anything works, I get browser forbidden error, despite of browsing catalogues function working. Also, to make it work, do I need to start new project as new ASP NEt Web application, then adding new class or did I mess something up? I am sorry in advance for all these different questions but I simply cannot find anything useful on the web explaining me all this stuff.

Comment: Get some basic OOP understaning. You can find some OOP tutorials here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656686.aspx

Comment: I literally have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you mean you want to know how a basic class is made? And how to override the `ToString` method?

Here is a small example:

```
public class Person
{
    protected string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        set { _name = value; }
        get { return _name; }
    }

    public Person()
    {
        _name = null;
    }
    public Person(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _name;
    }
}
```

For more information on the `ToString` method, see this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring

---

To use this you would do:

```
Person me = new Person("Deantwo");
Person you = new Person();
you.Name = "Ford Perfect";
Console.WriteLine("My name is " + me.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + you.ToString());
```

If you need more help with how to use objects and classes, take a look at the article @Ian H. linked to.
This: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656686.aspx

Comment: So how can I test it if it works in Visual Studio then?

Comment: Added an usage example.